# Using URL-safe keys in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go

We're migrating from the old AppEngine Datastore console to the new  console. Internally, we have times when we're trying to generate links to specific datastore entities.

For the old GAE console, you can use the encoded URL safe key to link to an entity, such as:

`return fmt.Sprintf("https://appengine.google.com/datastore/edit?key=%s", key)`

where `key` is the encoded URL-safe key from the entity.

However, in the new cloud console, Google returns "failed to load" when I try to load the URL:

`return fmt.Sprintf("https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/edit?key=%s", key)`

where `key` is the encoded URL-safe key from the entity.

It will load if I decode the key first and give the URL the namespace and kind, but only if it's the entity **query** page (not the edit page):

`return fmt.Sprintf("https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query?ns=%s&kind=%s&key=%s", namespace, kind, key)`

But the purpose of an encoded key is to not have to decode that.

So my question:

Is there a way to get the new cloud console to accept the encoded key and load the entity edit page?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with including the unencoded key? The encoded key can be decoded anyway, it doesn't add extra security.

Comment: Encoding allows us to not introduce errors or extra code when we're switching namespaces, kinds, etc. Having to be verbose about those means the code gets longer and much less flexible.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a very similar problem. I don't even mind if I do have to decode things, I just can't work out how to construct the edit URL key. It seems to be in the format `0/|12/EntityKind|13/id:0000000000` but I can't seem to figure out where the extra numbers (12 and 13) come from.

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out. The numbers are the length of the string following them (obviously that makes my previous example wrong, but oh well). That means I can actually generate the URL at least, but what a weird encoding.

Comment: wow, that's a bit convoluted, but at least it works to generate the URL. I'll pass this onto Google support as well.

Comment: @chris FYI google has updated things so you can use the URL safe keys with the new cloud console URLs.

Comment: @matthewdavie Well that's great. Makes things much easier for me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has updated the console to correctly process URL-safe keys, so this issue is now solved.